# ERROR! Invalid extra vars data supplied. '@./vars.yaml' could not be made into a dictionary

Tags: templates, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am not sure what is wrong with the following yaml

```
ansible -v local -c local  -i ../../../inventory/staging.yml -m template  -a "src=hamap.1.j2 dest=/tmp/tmp.txt"  --extra-vars=@./vars.1.yaml
```

I am expecting a file `/tmp/tmp.txt` to be generated.
I get the following error

> ERROR! Invalid extra vars data supplied. '@./vars.1.yaml' could not be made into a dictionary

I tried the following in the [ansible test site](https://ansible.sivel.net/test/)

It gives me a similar error message

> Error! ERROR! Invalid extra vars data supplied. '@variables.yml' could not be made into a dictionary

**./vars.1.yaml**

```
---
- Somevar:
  - somesubvar:
     - somevalue
```

**hamap.1.j2**

```
{% for somesubvar in Somevar %}
{{ somesubvar  }} # somevalue should come out here
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the following site and starting off really simply.
I was able to identify my problem. `-` indicates a sub value.

The [documents from ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html)

> YAML Basics
>   For Ansible, nearly every YAML file starts with a list. Each item in the list is a list of key/value pairs, commonly called a “hash” or a “dictionary”. So, we need to know how to write lists and dictionaries in YAML.

Esentailly I was trying to put a dictionary value `- Somevar` at the top of the yaml file structure. Which is expecting a simple list element. No `-` in front of it.

The following works in the test site.
https://ansible.sivel.net/test/

**./vars.1.yaml**

```
---
Somevar:
  - somesubvar:
     - somevalue
```

**hamap.1.j2**

```
{% for somesubvar in Somevar %}
{ somesubvar  } # somevalue should come out here
{% endfor %}
```